# How to define global, common iterations for all team projects in TFS 2010

Tags: version-control, tfs

**Background**

I am working to update around 40 Team Projects in a single collection under TFS 2010.  Each Team Project will use the same relative iteration paths to support common team queries, reports, dashboards etc.

**The Challenge**

Although the relative names of the iterations are the same, they do include the Team Project in the path which makes them distinct in terms of queries and reports etc.

My goals are:

1. Eliminate the considerable overhead of changing the iteration paths for each team query, report and other dependent artifact for every team project.  Ideally, I would drag and drop the artifacts from one project to the next without the need for modification.
2. Report or query based on a common iteration across all team projects

**Current Definition:**
Project A / Current Development / Iteration X, 
Project Z / Current Development / Iteration X ...

**Ideal Definition:**
Current Development / Iteration X

This would provide a truly common iteration that would meet the above stated objectives.

Any ideas on if and how this might be accomplished?

Comment: Why can't you use @Project? As in, `@Project/Current Development/Iteration X`?

Comment: Hm..., while you can enter the value, it does not recognize `@Project` with other characters. I wonder if you can make this change in the process template.

Comment: Hm.., I have the Agile process template exported. I check and there is "Iteration1Backlog.wiq" and in the query is the this snippet: `AND  [Source].[System.IterationPath] UNDER '$$PROJECTNAME$$\Iteration 1'`. You probably can manually create the query then add with the Process Template Editor that comes with "TFS Power Tools".

Comment: I actually think that will work.

Comment: I believe I am following you, could you provide an example?  Looking for syntax to enter for a Team Query - wont' help me with the Excel Reports though?

Comment: No example. I just closed the template. The queries can be saved to a file. Open one of the iteration queries within Visual Studio the click File > Save Query As...

Comment: I saved the query locally, modified the iteration path as you specified and received the same error as using @Project - no go

Answer (score 1):

This would certainly make a useful feature, but currently there's no OOTB support for it. You can use the `In` operator to avoid multiple `And` conditions. Then you can simply copy-paste the entire condition row to other queries.

```
Field           Operator    Value
Iteration Path  In          Project A\Current Development\Iteration X,Project Z\Current Development\Iteration 1
```

Comment: + 1 for a workaround that partially solves my challenges - this should work for Team Queries, but does not provide a solution for the excel reporting.  Thank you.